# Code snippets in IntelliSense bugged?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

As far as I remember I´ve never been able to insert snippets from the IntelliSense popup menu. If I, for instance, start typing `switch`, the IntelliSense menu will appear, and then I select the `switch` snippet and press, either tab or enter, but all I get is `switch` in my code.

The snippet does properly appear when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> and select the snipped from the list. Am I doing something wrong or is my VS bugged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to insert a snippet you need to type <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.  The first <kbd>Tab</kbd> inserts the selected word and the second <kbd>Tab</kbd> expands the snippet.

Comment: How did I freaking miss this!

Comment: @jsoldi it's easy to miss. I only found out because I had to fix bugs in snippets for the 2010 release.